# JSF: Why do UIComponents need a no-args constructor?

Tags: java, jsf

Without one, component renders ok, however, using AJAX with re-renderable target within it fails (IllegalStateException).

I guess UIComponents need to accord to JavaBeans spec. But why do they need the non-args constructor? If I call `UIComponent` from a template, I understand that runtime needs to initialize a class with a non-args constructor and then set any properties, but in this case I was adding the component programmatically as:

```
MyComponent comp = new MyComponent("foo", "bar");
getChildren().add(comp);
```

So I wasn't calling a non-args constructor, and I don't know why JSF would either as AJAX should only re-render the component, not create a new instance from the component class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling it, but JSF might need to instantiate the component.

Take a look at the [`StateHolder`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/StateHolder.html) interface (which is implemented by `UIComponent`). It explicitly states that a no-arg constructor is needed. And that's because this is a custom mechanism of saving and restoring state.

Comment: That seems to be the case, but the question is why (due to (de)serialization it seems)...

Comment: You were the first one to point out the JSF-specific serialization mechanism, with pointer to StateHolder. Picking as accepted answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that JSF components are automatically serialized and de-serialized between requests. Default constructors (while in theory not absolutely necessary) make this a lot easier and are required by the Serializable API.

From the [Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) docs:

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable
>   classes to be serialized, the subtype
>   may assume responsibility for saving
>   and restoring the state of the
>   supertype's public, protected, and (if
>   accessible) package fields. The
>   subtype may assume this responsibility
>   only if the class it extends has an
>   accessible no-arg constructor to
>   initialize the class's state. It is an
>   error to declare a class Serializable
>   if this is not the case. The error
>   will be detected at runtime.

Comment: a note: java serialization does not use the constructor. JSF performs its own 'serialization'.

Comment: @Bozho: so this means JSF *does use* a no-args constructor for (de)serialization while normal Java serialization does not?

Answer (score 2):

The JSF framework must be able to instantiate new instances of `UIComponent` classes. There is no requirement for the UI tree to be held in RAM between requests and when this is the case, reflection is used to restore it.

*`UIComponent` implementations do not implement `Serializable` and are not JavaBeans (per the strict definition). Implementing `Serializable` would not be useful because components can have a 1:n relationship with their state (e.g. they are the child of a repeating control).*

Comment: Interesting note about 1:n relationship. I thought (without really thinking about it) that when a loop is re-rendered, old children are trashed and new ones created? Is JSF intelligent enough to somehow retain and re-render old instances while creating new ones / modifying some of the old on the same run?

Comment: @Tuukka Mustonen - the exact behaviour is defined by the components. See `setRowIndex(int)` in http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Having read that, I think I'm still missing something. Anyway, that might be a subject of totally another question. Thanks for support!